# Timbre macro 'p' can't be resolved but other Timbre macros can be

Tags: clojure, profiling, timbre

Whenever I try to include a Timbre `p` statement in a function I get an error:

**project.clj**

```
 (defproject sketch "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
      :description "FIXME: write description"
      :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
      :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
                :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
      :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                     [com.taoensso/timbre "3.1.1"]])
```

**core.clj**

```
(ns user (:require [taoensso.timbre :as timbre])) 
(timbre/refer-timbre)

(defn tst [a]
  (p :tf (+ a a)))
```

**Output** (cider/nrepl)

```
 Unable to resolve symbol: p in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:2:3)
```

But other Timbre functions/macros like `profile` and `spy` work fine.

Comment: It might be worth noting that: 

1. profiling doesn't work for cljs
2. profiling moved to a new project, [tufte](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tufte)
3. tufte version 2.0.1 [doesn't work in cljs](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tufte/issues/33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` profiling macro [is not exposed with refer-timbre](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/blob/master/src/taoensso/timbre.clj#L518), the documentation seems to be outdated.

```
(require
   '[taoensso.timbre.profiling :as profiling :refer (pspy pspy* profile defnp)])
```

As [you see here](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/blob/master/src/taoensso/timbre/profiling.clj#L30), `p` is just an alias for `pspy`

```
 (defmacro p [id & body] `(pspy ~id ~@body)) ; Alias
```

So you can use `pspy` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the time it took while you are developing the [time](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/time) function can be enough.

```clj
(time (some-work))
```